# Teamcity build with YAML file as input

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-9.0, teamcity-7.0

I'm trying to use a YAML file as a standard-in to teamcity to pass build parameters. (user will copy the yaml file as stdin) .

which build runner should i use to achieve this. I can find command line as a build runner.but it simply use arguments to a script ? ( i can do the same) but is there any way that i can copy configuration details to teamcity without an argument to a script ?

Answer (score 0):

Jetbrains seems to prefere [not do go with yaml](https://www.theregister.com/2021/04/29/jetbrains_takes_teamcity_to_cloud/). But you can still give XML or Kotlin DSL a try:

> You can store project settings in the XML format or in the Kotlin language and define settings programmatically using the Kotlin-based DSL. [Kotlin DSL](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/teamcity/kotlin-dsl.html)

```
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2019_2.*
import jetbrains.buildServer.configs.kotlin.v2019_2.buildSteps.script

version = "2021.1"

project {
  buildType {
    id("HelloWorld")
    name = "Hello world"
    steps {
        script {
            scriptContent = "echo 'Hello world!'"
        }
    }
  }
}
```